# Passing back the result of a this.props.functionName() to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chat

In React JS I have 2 files:

**File 1: Chat.js**

This file calls numerous custom components and provides them with custom functions as props.

**File 2: PreviewChatBox.js**

This file shows a preview of multiple chats. When I call the function that has been sent from chat.js (load Chat) it changes a state in Chat.js to an integer from one of the previewchat components.

I need to be able to access that component in Chat.js but I can't seem to be able to pass the variable back.

**CODE:**

**File 1: Chat.js**

```
render(){
  return(
    <PreviewChatBox onClicked={() => this.previewClicked()}/>
)}
```

**File 2: PreviewChatBox.js**

```
 <div onClick={() => this.props.onClicked()} key={value}> 
     <p> {element[0]}{element[1]}{element[2]} </p>
 </div>
```

So I can call the method without any problem but I cannot pass the key back to chat.js

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using a callback function?

Chat.js

```
<PreviewChatBox 
     onClicked={() => this.previewClicked()} 
     updateKey((newKey) => this.setState({newKey}) />
```

Now your child component should be able to update the state of `Chat.js` by accessing the updateKey function from props.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps match your use case, but I'm able to get this working by referencing the previewClicked method directly in Chat.js without using an arrow function and passing the key directly to the onClick behavior in PreviewChatBox.js

File 1 : Chat.js

```
previewClicked = (val) => {
    console.log(val);
};

render() {
    return (
        <PreviewChatBox onClicked={ this.previewClicked }/>
        )
};
```

File 2 : PreviewChatBox.js

```
const element = ['abc','def','ghi'];
const value = 2;

return (    
<div onClick={ () => props.onClicked(value) } key={value}> 
 <p> {element[0]}{element[1]}{element[2]} </p>
</div>
);
```